# how to define a state in python for reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I need to create a state space for my RL problem which has about 10 state variables each which contains about 2 or 3 values for the variables. That would make the state space about 600,000 states. How do I implement this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the number of states in your problem, maybe you should consider in using some kind of [function approximation](http://incompleteideas.net/book/ebook/node85.html) instead of using a tabular representation.

If finally you decide to use a table with 600k rows and as much columns as actions, maybe a [pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) could work.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for, I am thinking about using a Neural network for the function approximation but if that's the case do i need to one hot encode the 600k states and input that into the network?

Comment: Yes, I guess that if your variables are categorical and you want to use a neural network, probably you should use hot encoding. If they are numerical, maybe you can treat them as continuous values, even they are discrete. Another option could be use a different kind function approximator, which is able to digest caterogical data, such as decision trees.

Comment: Thanks this helped alot. When implementing this in python can you suggest how I could implement the transitions from a state to another given an action. Any reference would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Thanks! This is totally another question, the state transition function it is not related with the RL algorithm. Usually, your environment is a function, `env(s,a)`, that takes current state `s` and a given action `a`, and returns the next state `s'`, a flag signaling if the episode has finished, and sometimes a reward (the reward could be seen as an independent function).

Comment: Here [https://gym.openai.com/envs/#classic_control] you can see some typical toy environments, they are useful to understand the environment concept (probably you could find simpler Python implemantations of these environments if you google it).